# Path/File Access error for LoginForm.show

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a login form for my workbook, I was all finished on the code side of things.

I am getting a massive problem after enabling the code, it runs fine until the book is closed, upon re-opening the book I get a Path/File Access error, also it deletes all contents of the form, text boxes, labels, and togglebutton. It then states a mistmatch error on code tested fine before closing the book.

I've narrowed it down to the code highlighted, specifically the `LoginForm.show`.

Can someone suggest any actions at all?

***Sheet9 (ListSheets)***

```
Option Explicit



Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("k4:r8")) Is Nothing Then


    If Target.Value = "Ð" Then
    Target.Value = "Ï"
    Exit Sub
    End If
     If Target.Value = "x" Then Target.Value = "Ð"
    If Target.Value = "Ï" Then Target.Value = "x"
    If Target.Value = Empty Then Target.Value = "Ð"
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J4:J8")) Is Nothing Then
If Target.Value = "Ð" Then
    Range("J" & Target.Row & ":r" & Target.Row).Value = "Ï"
    Exit Sub
    End If
     If Target.Value = "x" Then Range("J" & Target.Row & ":r" & Target.Row).Value = "Ð"
    If Target.Value = "Ï" Then Range("J" & Target.Row & ":r" & Target.Row).Value = "x"
    If Target.Value = Empty Then Range("J" & Target.Row & ":r" & Target.Row).Value = "Ð"
End If
End Sub
```

***This Workbook***

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
closeworkbook
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
LoginForm.Show
End Sub
```

***Assorted Macros***

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckUser()
Dim UserRow, SheetCol As Long
Dim SheetNm As String
With Sheet9
.Calculate

If .Range("B7").Value = Empty Then 'Incorrect Username
    MsgBox "Please Enter a correct user name"
    Exit Sub
End If

If .Range("B6").Value <> True Then 'Incorrect password
    MsgBox "Please Enter a correct password"
    Exit Sub
End If

LoginForm.Hide
.Range("B4,B5").ClearContents
UserRow = .Range("B7").Value 'User Row

For SheetCol = 11 To 18
SheetNm = .Cells(3, SheetCol).Value 'Sheet Name
If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Value = "Ð" Then
    Sheets(SheetNm).Unprotect "123"
    Sheets(SheetNm).Visible = xlSheetVisible
End If

If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Value = "Ï" Then
    Sheets(SheetNm).Protect "123"
    Sheets(SheetNm).Visible = xlSheetVisible
End If

If .Cells(UserRow, SheetCol).Value = "x" Then Sheets(SheetNm).Visible = xlVeryHidden
Next SheetCol
End With
End Sub

Sub closeworkbook()
Sheet8.Activate
Dim wksht As Worksheet
For Each wksht In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
If wksht.Name <> "Login" Then wksht.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
Next wksht
ThisWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Comment: There's not enough code here for anyone to be able to make an informed guess about your problem.  What happens in `closeworkbook` for example?

Comment: @TimWilliams I've updated the body of the code to show you the whole squence I thought relevant.

Comment: @TimWilliams - Further updates now, cearly depicting each bulk of code

Comment: I don't see any obvious issues there.  What code runs when `LoginForm` runs?  Do you have code in the userform activate event?

Comment: @TimWilliams, I got the soruce file in the end and there are lines of code missing from the tutorial on the youtube video. However, even are replacing these and then finally replacing the whole code, paste and copy style, the sheet still didn't work properly

I think i'm left with no choice but to transfer my sheets to another workbook! 

I spoke to the creator of the book and he told me it may be a programme issue involving control source, and instread to write it in code. 

On this occasion I have decided to use the free source file. I still thank you very much for your help on this.